# How to tell Google that I tried to perform the task?

Tags: java, email, gmail, google-settings

I want to create a java program that sends mails from my java app. I am using Gmail as the email provider and their servers.

My code works there are no errors or bugs, but Google security wont allow me to run it. It blocks the process.

Here is what I get when I visit my Google account after I run my java app:

[image]

Does anyone know if I can change that anywhere in my Google account settings?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your emailing service is being blocked because google thinks it not secure(which it isnt)

In order to allow request to go through you must turn on *"Let less secure apps access my account"* in your gmail settings.

[here are](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en) 2 [articles](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) on this.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me how to solve the problem!